# convert a dictionary in a series to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a dictionary object in a <pandas.core.series.series> and I want to convert it to dataframe. please find the example below

`file["floordetails"]` is column of a dataframe, that has a below series

```
print(file["floordetails"])

0          {'floorname':'2','room':'1'}
1          {'floorname':'4','room':'1'}
2          {'floorname':'5','room':'1'}
3          {'floorname':'1'}
4          {'floorname':'2','room':'1'}
    ...
998          {'floorname':'2'}
999          {'floorname':'2'}
1000         {'floorname':'2','room':'1'}
```

Initial I tried to convert it to dataframe using `pd.Dataframe(list(file["floordetails"]))`, but it gave an error: `'float' object has no attribute 'keys'`.

So I used `pd.Dataframe([i for i in file["floordetails"] if pd.notna(i)])`, which worked but the last record was missing (there are 1000 records in total, but end result was 999 records).

Expected result:

| floorname | room |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 1 |  |

Note: few records may or may not have `room`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.tolist()`

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(file["floordetails"].dropna().tolist())
```

Comment: Again the last record is missing

Comment: Strange. Will you please send the result of `print(file['floordetails'].tail(5))`?

Comment: ya it is!!. tail(5) works perfectly , it gave me the last 5 records

Comment: What does `file["floordetails"].isna().sum()` return?

Comment: `err :"numpy.int64" object is not iterable`

Comment: Try `type(file["floordetails"])`

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.series.series'>

Comment: Wow, so I have no idea what that `sum` call isn't working. Are there are any NaNs in the `floordetails` column?